# Call abstract method from abstract class constructor

Tags: c#, oop, abstract-class

I would like to ask what are the risks of having something as follows:

```
abstract public class HtmlTemplateBuilder
{
    HtmlSource source;

    protected HtmlTemplateBuilder()
    {
        LoadTemplates();
    }

    public abstract void LoadTemplates();
}
```

The risk is if a derived class derives from the derived class:

## DerivedClass2 -> #DerivedClass1 -> HtmlTemplateBuilder

This can be solved by sealing #DerviedClass1, but are there any more risks or better practices for implementing this functionality?

Thanks

Comment: What risk do you see in your example ? Can you be more specific ?

Comment: Resharper says (and I understand why): virtual member call in constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this link which explains the perils with simple easy to understand examples

https://blogs.msmvps.com/peterritchie/2012/04/25/virtual-method-call-from-constructor-what-could-go-wrong/

I would remove the call to LoadTemplates from constructor and call Initialise on it when the templates actually need to be loaded and used.

```
abstract public class HtmlTemplateBuilder
{
    HtmlSource source;
    object locker = new object();
    private bool initialised;

    protected HtmlTemplateBuilder()
    {
    }

    protected void Initialise()
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            if(initialised)
            {
                LoadTemplates();
                initialised = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public abstract void LoadTemplates();
}
```

Comment: This is more or less the risk I explained, in my example the responsibility of the implementation is on the derived class. I asked for better/alternative solutions that are not risky.

Comment: I would lazy load templates. Not only it reduces the possible risk that someone could reintriduce the risk in future by changing your classes, it also keeps the objects lightweight until the point of actual usage. In the first point where you need templates to be loaded, check if they are loaded by maintaining state in a boolean flag, otherwise load.

Comment: The link provided is broken. This works: https://blogs.msmvps.com/peterritchie/2012/04/25/virtual-method-call-from-constructor-what-could-go-wrong/

Comment: Thanks Raj. I've fixed the link.

Answer (score 1):

The situation in which this pattern bit me is as follows: at some later stage you want to add  a specialized `HtmlTemplateBuilder`, which can load different templates based on some criteria unknown to the class itself (maybe you decide you want some cool templates on a specific day of the year). That is:

```
public class SpecialHtmlTemplateBuilder : HtmlTemplateBuilder
{
    private bool someCondition;

    public override void LoadTemplates()
    {
        if (someCondition)
        {
            LoadTemplatesSet1();
        }
        else
        {
            LoadTemplatesSet2();
        }
    }
}
```

But how are you going to pass `someCondition` to the class? The following won't work:

```
public class SpecialHtmlTemplateBuilder : HtmlTemplateBuilder
{
    private bool someCondition;

    public SpecialHtmlTemplateBuilder (bool someCondition)
    {
        this.someCondition = someCondition;
    }

    // ...
}
```

because the assignment of `this.someCondition` will be done *after* calling the base constructor, i.e., *after* `LoadTemplates()` is called. Note that sealing derived classes does *not* solve this problem.

The way to solve this is as @Rahul Misra described: add an explicit `Initialize` method and call that after the constructor.